# How to get output as Tabular Format from Shell scripting?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have data in text file in below format

```
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/text1.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/text2.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/EMP2/text3.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/ACS1/text4.txt
```

I want output as below

```
                 Path Name                                         File Name
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/           text1.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/           text2.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/EMP2/               text3.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/ACS1/               text4.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Pleas edit your question to indicate what you already tried. This way you can avoid that contributors point you in a direction you already know doesn't work. Also, do you want to have the "Header" line in the output, or was this only for illustration purposes?

Comment: How wide should the first column be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` and `column` commands like:

```
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{print "PathName FileName"}{a="";for(i=2;i<=NF-1;i++){a=a"/"$i};a=a"/";print a"\t"$NF}' file_name  | column -t
```

It will print like:

```
PathName                                                  FileName
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/  text1.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/  text2.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/EMP2/      text3.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/ACS1/      text4.txt
```

If you want to keep the spaces between words `Path Name and File Name`, then you can delimit by tab instead of space.

```
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{print "         Path Name\tFile Name"}{a="";for(i=2;i<=NF-1;i++){a=a"/"$i};a=a"/";print a"\t"$NF}' file_name  | column -t -s $'\t'
```

```
         Path Name                                        File Name
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/  text1.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/  text2.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/EMP2/      text3.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/ACS1/      text4.txt
```

Comment: Shell scripting?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Just one way to do text-processing.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille awk is a standard tool when shell scripting and [part of posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html).

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav it really helped me in solving the scenario, but the only thing is that i'm getting only one space of gap between Pathname and FIle Names values ... i mean between path and text1.txt .. please help on this

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav I'm getting once space gap as explained above when i'm sending the output through mail command to my mail ID

Comment: @VenkataAbhilash in the end I have used `print a"\t"$NF`, here `a` is first column and `$NF` is second column, so you can add spaces before and after `a and $NF`. Like `a"    \t"$NF`.

Comment: What format does your mail client expect?  HTML?

Comment: @PhilipCouling  Seriously?

Comment: @PhilipCouling, indeed, I thought that was the challenge.  But I was wrong, since the answer has been accepted.  The "seriously" was for you explaining me what "awk" was.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille No the term [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) usually refers to the available commands as well as the interpreter.  I'll admit there is some ambiguity.  It's a common enough trope here: shell script questions that don't want any external commands must explicitly ask for that since writing anything in `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, usually involves external commands.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav, when i'm usinf column command it is throwing "ksh: column:  not found" error... for example my script name is Find_Files.sh ...its not ksh .. what is the substitute of column command in sh scripts . Please suggest

Comment: @VenkataAbhilash make sure the `column`, command is installed. Also do not worry about `.sh`, bash does not care about file endings. Make sure you script starts with shebang, like `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

ksh only (eg. printf is a shell built-in)

```
# find the longest path name
MP=0
while read
do
  P="${REPLY%/*}"
  PS=${#P}
  [ $PS -le $MP ] || MP=$PS
done < /tmp/test.txt

# calculate where to put "Path Name"
(( MP++ ))
T="Path Name"
TS=${#T}
(( SS = ( MP - TS ) / 2 ))
(( SP = ( MP - TS ) % 2 ))
printf "%${SS}s%s%${SS}s%${SP}s %s\n" "" "$T" "" "" "File Name"

# format the input text
while read
do
  P="${REPLY%/*}"
  F="${REPLY##*/}"
  printf "%-${MP}s %s\n" "$P/" "$F"
done < /tmp/test.txt
```

You may understand why some weaker of heart revert to using POSIX commands.

Comment: Thanks for the bash only solution. [Q] Wherefrom does the `$REPLY` shell variable gets its value?

Comment: When "read" doesn't specify a variable to store what is read, the variable REPLY receives that input.   I don't know if my script works with bash, I only use ksh.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl + column,you could run something along the lines of

```
perl -pE 'BEGIN{say "Path\tFile\n"} s!.*/\K!\t!' input | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

We may employ `tbl`, `groff` which is GNU's  adaptation of `nroff`, and the line editor `ed`.

We first break apart into dirname and basename each line and then inject `tbl` code at the beginning and end of the file.
The tbl code is to center the header columns and left justify the rest.

The `tbl` utility spits working groff code which  `groff` then operats upon to gets the desired output. The `grep`  is to deletes empty lines.

```
$ ed -s inp <<\eof | tbl | groff -Tascii | grep .
,s|[^/]*$|@&|
1i
.TS
tab(@);
c c
l l.
PATH NAME@FILE NAME
.
$a
.TE
.
,p
Q
eof
```

**Output:**

```
                       PATH NAME                           FILE NAME
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/   text1.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/WGS1/CLM/   text2.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/EMP2/       text3.txt
/gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles/WCC_CDHP_LITES/ACS1/       text4.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source really is this file, you can do it like this:

```
(echo full_path; cat input) | 
  csv-add-split -c full_path -e / -n parent,name -r |
  csv-cut -c parent,name -S
```

But if your source is a directory path you can do it like this:

```
csv-ls -R -c parent,name /gpfs/pcenterdata/test/SrcFiles -S
```

These commands come from csv-nix-tools (https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools).

Answer (score 0):

Like Prvt_Yadav, you can use awk & column, but awk's "gensub" function can be used to extract the required text.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "PathName\tFileName"} {f=gensub(/.*\//,"\\1","1"); p=gensub(/[^/]*$/,"\\1","1"); print p"\t"f}' | column -t
```